# How do we build custom forms in a sharepoint solution?

Tags: custom-form

Sharepoint designer is not allowed. The forms must contain fields with references to list items but may contain custom asp controls as well, which we whish to use later in the process.
The target isn't always to replace the original new, edit and display forms but to create extra forms too. Currently, we create custom forms by copying the existing base forms and edit them by hidding the zonetemplates and add our custom fields below. It aint the most elegant way, but at the moment the best result we have so far.

What about security questions with custom forms?
We have reasons to believe that the security will be more complex if we build custom forms. Custom forms are opened by ribbon buttons, what about the security? How can we narrow down the acces to such custom forms to authorized personel, groups, users?

Comment: Why SPD would be disallowed ? It can simplifies a lot such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sharepoint Designer isn't allowed your best option would be infopath  :  http://www.marclenferna.com/blog/archive/2009/01/18/how-to.-publish-your-infopath-form-to-sharepoint--a.aspx

You can narrow down the security to the form in the list permissions:  http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=8d9e2a99-f288-47c2-916b-2f32864f7b82&ID=533&Web=5e4647a0-e7d0-4626-b71c-b1ff06402465

Comment: can I put custom asp controls in infopath forms?

Comment: you can put custom code in the infopath. It depends on how complex you are wanting it to be. I would suggest trying to do everything with the available controls in infopath. Most of the time these are sufficient. -Hope this helps